# How do I upload a plist file to my server and do I have to do anything special on the server-side?

Tags: php, objective-c, cocoa, apache, osx-snow-leopard

How do I upload a plist file from my desktop app to my server? 
Is there anything special I have to do on the server-side to handle this? 
I have a linux server running Apache with PHP. Once I have the file uploaded, I'm going to use the pList file to supply data to an iPhone app.

Comment: A plist file is just a file. You don't say what you want to do with the file, or what kind of service platform you're running, or what your goals are with its data...

Comment: I'm going to use the file to supply data to my iPhone app. My server is a linux server running apache and php.

Comment: It looks like you’re asking two questions here: (1) how to upload a plist file, which is the same as how to upload a generic file, and (2) how to parse plists in your server. For the first question, there already are many other questions on Stack Overflow with answers explaining how to do that from a Cocoa Touch application. For the second question, I’m not sure if it’s really a duplicate. Also, you’ve said that your server runs Linux+Apache+PHP but you’ve tagged your question with Cocoa and Snow Leopard. It’d help if you edited your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways is to upload it using a POST to the server. When you add files i found [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) to be very nice. Anything you need to upload is on this page.

On the server side it will arrive in the $FILES array (this is for PHP).